# Installing pygame

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pygame

I'm completely new to Python. I used Macports to install Python, as per advice that the pre-installed version of Python is not ideal on OSX.

I also ran the Pygame installer for OSX.

When I go into the Python console and type:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
```

it works fine (i.e., returns `(0,6)`) if I'm in my root directory.

If I try this elsewhere, I get the error:

```
File "< stdin >", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your PYTHONPATH set to?

Comment: I think you've found the nub of something I don't understand. In .bash_profile I have:
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2012-10-25_at_20:28:42: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

Is there another thing that is PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: Inside Terminal, execute `echo $PYTHONPATH`, the post the output. Also, do you know the path of where pygame was installed?

Comment: $PYTHONPATH returns nothing, just an empty line. 

I'm not sure where it installed, I have a folder called pygame in /developer/python/pygame, but it only seems to contain docs and examples.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I have install python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 with homebrew on my OSX, and first attempt also failed. I thought it may be pygame'fault.
Just try another mkpg/src
http://pygame.org/ftp/

Comment: I think the problem here is the question is bad. The answer is commensurate with the question, which makes the answer look poor. In actuality, I think the answer is a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

To use pygame on OS X make sure you are running it in 32bit mode.

```
arch -i386 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/idle2.7 -n
```

is an example of a terminal command to start idle in 32bit mode to run pygame code.